# I can't add a string to itself

Tags: java

I'm new to java and trying to add a string to itself (plus other strings also) and it runs but doesn't do anything at all, as in it just outputs "test", which is what it is before
everything else seems to work

```
package chucknorris;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input string:");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        int length = input.length();
        String output = "test";
        

        for (int current = 0;current <= length;current++) {
            String letter = input.substring(current, current);
            output = output + letter + " ";

            if (current == length) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }
        }

        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to check the documentation of the String.substring(int, int) method.

Comment: `foo.substring(n,n).equals("")`

Comment: `input.substring(current, current)` <- I recommend reading the substring methods documentation about what the 2 arguments represent and then thinking about (or testing) what happens when both parameters are the same: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)

Comment: It is a very common pattern to see ranges defined as inclusive at the lower bound and exclusive at the upper bound, and for the exclusivity to override the inclusivity so `[x,x]` will include nothing. This follows the behavior of common `i = 0; i < limit` type loops, and maintains the invariant that `length == upperbound - lowerbound`. So it's not just strings that behave that way - almost everything will, and arguably it is bad to code things that do not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Solution, but you should use StringBuilder if you want to edit a String for a multiple times

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input string:");
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    int length = input.length();
    String output = "test";


    for (int current = 0;current <= length;current++) {

        if (current >= length) {
            break;
        }
        String letter = input.substring(current, current + 1);
        output = output + letter;

    }

    System.out.println(output);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use concat for the string concatenation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Input string:");
  String input = scanner.nextLine();
  int length = input.length();
  String output = "test";
        
  output = output.concat(output).concat(input).concat("");

  System.out.println(output);     
}
```